# Deploy Failing For Tibco BW 6 Application Using Maven

Tags: maven-3, tibco-business-works, businessworks

I am deploying my Tibco application ( built in BW 6.x version) via maven 3.5.3 version but deployment is failing. Not sure why its not able to deploy.

Below is error message.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.323 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-08T10:01:12Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.tibco.plugins:bw6-maven-plugin:1.3.1:bwinstal
l (default-bwinstall) on project EmployeeApplication.application: Failed to depl
oy BW Application : Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal c
om.tibco.plugins:bw6-maven-plugin:1.3.1:bwinstall (default-bwinstall) on project
 EmployeeApplication.application: Failed to deploy BW Application
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.ja
va:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (
LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreaded
Builder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleSt
arter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
```

I have attached POM file used for my application.

Comment: We need more info.. ur pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

check the dependencies in the parent pom and also the version has to be the same in all the dependent modules

Comment: I got issue resolved. Port  was not accessible for bw admin hence this issue. Now deployed code locally and can run buil sucessfully. Thanks for your replies.